# Dynamic execution in PostgreSQL just like that in sql-server

Tags: postgresql, sql-server-2008

Dynamic EXecution structure in sql ,

```
Set @Params = N'@DataTmp NVarChar(Max) OutPut'

    Set @StrSqlTmp = 'Set @DataTmp = 
                Convert(VarChar(Max), (' + @BaseQuery + ' For Xml Path(''item'')))'

    Exec Sp_ExecuteSql @StrSqlTmp, @Params, @DataTmp = @DataTmp OutPut
```

In want the alternative method for this process in postgresql.
Can anyone knows the solutions for this? Plz reply

Comment: You need to change everything to work in Postgres `Sp_ExecuteSql ` this should be changed, So show that procedure or convert it to Postgres

Comment: How can i dynamically execute query in postgresql?

Comment: DO -http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html or pl/pgsql-http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL isn't Microsoft SQL Server, and for features outside the SQL standard it usually differs from how Microsoft's T-SQL does things.

To execute dynamic SQL use PL/PgSQL's `EXECUTE` statement. Preferably with the `format` function. You can use it in a PL/PgSQL function or, if you don't need to pass parameters, in a `DO` block.

I don't know exactly what the code above does since I don't know MS SQL well at all. The [plpgsql manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) has some simple examples of dynamic SQL you can use to get started, and you could also look at the [dynamic-sql](/questions/tagged/dynamic-sql) tag on Stack Overflow; search for [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql)[dynamic-sql](/questions/tagged/dynamic-sql).